# Symfony Bundle for allowing users to message each other

Tags: symfony, notifications, rabbitmq

I'm developing a web app that needs to be able to allow users to send each other messages.  It should work such that when a user is online and they send a message then if the recipient is online they would get a notification on screen and be able to know they have received a message (without them necessarily doing a page refresh)

The message should be part of a conversation thread rather than an email (although one way of notifying users that are not logged in would be to email them)

Are there any bundles out there that do this sort of thing or do I need a combination of Symfony and JS to allow for the realtime update of the users webpage ?

I have looked at things like rabbitMQ and FOSmessageBundle but I haven't figured out how these can get me the user notification back to an open user session.

Thoughts or guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The prefered technology to realtime message exchange is [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Please let me introduce to basic workflow of websocket.

Let's take foo and bar as example users

#### Workflow of a chat

- `foo` establish connection to the websocket `server`
- `bar` establish connection to the websocket `server`
- `foo` send `hello` message in the connection
- `server` received the message and broadcast to `bar's` connection
- Bar receive a message from the connection payload and display it

The client side is javascript, you haven't the choice IMHO

For the server side you can do this in PHP

I'll suggest you a not so known, but good, library called [Woketo](https://github.com/Nekland/Woketo).

A node JS environment is more common, mainly because node js is better than PHP with asyncronous things. It use less memory per process too

Feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

I have built such functionality recently, it’s pretty straightforward. I used this bundle that does the pub/sub functionality and gets your websockets working properly. The only thing you have to do yourself is record messages on the database (if you want to) and make each pub/sub point to each other so messages go from one user to another.

[GOS RATCHET BUNDLE](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle)

UPDATE 2020:

There is a great self-hosted alternative pub-sub that bundles natively with Symfony: [Mercure](https://github.com/dunglas/mercure)

Comment: Ah, I think I might have looked at this some time ago but I couldn't figure out how to make sense of it.

Comment: @MB. There are working examples within the documentation, if you block somewhere you can ask it here with the piece of code that you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you for this. My senior developer was pushing me to use Cometchat because he was not confident enough about FOS and GOS bundles but after reviewing their plans and pricing I don't think small startups like ours can afford them. Also some of the reviews were not good. It's a shame that there is no good self-hosted chat service out there for developers to use with confidence. If anyone knows of any service please do let me know.

Comment: I would rather recommend Mercure. Having tried both, I would rather have an instance running in a separate container and you can have as many applications as you want bridging over the same instance